# Saving taken picture on Android is always 0 byte

Tags: android, save, android-camera

I'm trying to save a picture after taking one with `PictureCallback`. Here is the function :

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
{
    FileOutputStream imageFileOS = null;

    try {
         imageFileOS = openFileOutput("imageTarget", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         imageFileOS.write(data);
         imageFileOS.flush();
         imageFileOS.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         Log.i("Error", "FIle Not Found");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
         Log.i("erreur", "IOException");
    }
}
```

But when I connect my phone to my computer, the file size is always 0 byte, and I can't open it.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` is added to my manifest.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: How many bytes are in "data"?  Do you see exceptions appearing in logcat?  (If you change your IOException handler to `throw new RuntimeException("file write failed", e)` then your program will blow up when something goes wrong.)

Comment: There are 246284 bytes in data, which seems good for a frontal camera picture. **Edit :** The program continues even after replacing my IOException

Comment: If you're successfully opening, writing data, and closing the file, then it doesn't make any sense for the file to be present but empty.  Is something else subsequently truncating the file?  If you open the file immediately after closing it (i.e. still in `onPictureTaken()`), are you able to read data back out of it?

Comment: Yes I can read it. If I go to my gallery on the device, I can display the picture, but it is saved at the end of the gallery and not at the beginning :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openFileOutput` writes to your internal file system.  You will not be able to access this easily from your phone unless it is rooted or you have the app in debug mode and you use the run-as command. The `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission doesn't help you in this case.

I suggest checking out this article for more info http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: No more success, it's still at 0 byte when I browse the picture :/